# How to create QR code from our input images in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an expressjs app. I want to create a QR code containing an image that I uploaded. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/xiongbinsh/full/goyobm According to our input image, they are creating a QR code. If I create an API, can we do the same idea in exprssjs?

```
app.post('/generate', (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text;
  const errorLevel = req.body.error_level;
  const userSize = parseInt(req.body.size);

  // Determine the QR size.
  let QRsize = -1;
  if (userSize === 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < sizes[errorLevel].length; i++) {
      if (text.length < sizes[errorLevel][i]) {
        QRsize = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (text.length < sizes[errorLevel][userSize - 1]) {
      QRsize = userSize;
    }
  }

  // Check if the text is too long.
  if (QRsize === -1) {
    if (userSize === 0) {
      if (errorLevel === 'H') {
        res.send('Too much text.');
      } else {
        res.send('Too much text. Try decreasing the error level.');
      }
    } else {
      res.send('Too much text. Try decreasing the error level or increasing the size.');
    }
    return;
  }

  // Generate the QR code.
  const qr = qrcode(QRsize, errorLevel);
  qr.addData(text);
  qr.make();

  // Generate the controls QR code.
  const controls = qrcode(QRsize, errorLevel);
  controls.addData(text);
  controls.make(true);

  // Generate the halftone QR code.
  const halftoneQRImage = halftoneQR(qr.returnByteArray(), controls.returnByteArray());

  // Send the halftone QR code image to the user.
  res.type('image/png').send(halftoneQRImage);
});
```